# When trying to install application ApplicationInsights Package i'm getting few errors

Tags: c#, nuget, azure-application-insights

when trying to install ApplicationInsights using this command `Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights -Version 2.9.1` I'm getting following error message

```
Install-Package : 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Collections'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights -Version 2.9.1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

How can i fix this

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?  When I search NuGet's source code for that message, it only appears for pack (creating packages), never install or restore.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013..